# tangent plane to surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I was wondering if somebody could check this question from schuam's outline for "Vector analysis" and tell me if this is a valid solution or has a typo...

**Execise 3.27**

Find an equation of the tangent plane to the surface $x^2+2xy^2-3z^3 = 6$ at the point P(1,2,1).

**Solution:**

We have
$F_x = 2x + 2y^2$, $F_y = 2x$, $F_z = 3z^2.$

**(At this point i'm wondering: is this Schuam's outline problem correct?)**

Why isn't
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=F_y = 4xy,\,\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=F_z = -9z^2$$

Is there's something i'm missing or misunderstanding?

Here's the rest of the solution for reference.

---

Thus, at the point, the normal to the surface (And the tangent plane) is $N(P)=[10,2,3]$

The tangent plane E at P has the form $10x+2y+3z=b$. Substituting $P$ in the equation gives $b=10+4+3=17$.  Thus $10x_+2y+3z=17$ is an equation for the tangent plane at $P$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is wrong. Note that
$$
F_x=2x+2y^2,\\
F_y=4xy\neq 2x,\\
F_z=-9z^2\neq 3z^2.
$$
Then, at the point $P=(1,2,1)$, you get the normal of the plane $(10,8,-9)$.